# Physics Based Animation in Blender to prevent model clipping

Tags: physics, motion-capture, clipping

I'm new to Blender and I'd like to know something I've been asking myself for a few weeks now:
Is it possible to add physics to the animation in Blender in order to make the model not clip inside itself?

For example, in mocap, when I put my hand on my chest, because the model and I don't have the exact same proportions his hand will cross slightly inside his chest and then I'll need to readjust the animation manually, but It is possible to add physics? then the chest and hand would collide, and they wouldn't be able to clip onto each other.

I've been searching for weeks but I can't find the right term for this, I don't know if there is a specific term for this technique.

The only thing I found was Cascadeur Software, but I saw that apparently it allows clipping to continue happening.
I would be happy if someone could explain to me or name this technique so I can research more about it, any information is welcome.

Comment: AFAIK you can do either use physics (on per frame basis) or animate. This is the difference between the animated checkbox on or off in rigid body settings. Since i assume you wanna animate your hand and your chest - i would say: no, it is not possible. Because only with physics you have collision.